# Restoring JSplitPane splitter to "default" location

Tags: swing, position, splitter, jsplitpane

I have a `JSplitPane` that has a `JTable` on the top part and a panel with labels and `JTextFields` on the bottom part. The splitter is set before adding using this function:

```
splitPane.setResizeWeight(1.0);
```

Now, I have a button that "hides" the bottom panel with this code:

```
splitPane.setDividerLocation(splitPane.getHeight());
splitPane.setEnabled(false);
```

Basically you can see the splitter at the bottom (which is what I want) but you can't do anything with it. Now, how do I get it back to the default position (the one giving the bottom panel the room it needs)?

I know I could use this by memorizing the relative position of the splitter before I push the button, but is there any function that will "refresh" my splitter to the location it needs to be to fulfill the condition of the `setResizeWeight(1.0)` function?

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done by doing the following:

```
splitPane.setDividerLocation(-1);
```